# How does one show a matrix is irreducible and reducible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How does one show a matrix is irreducible and reducible? An example would also be great.

I know that a matrix is reducible if and only if it can be placed into block upper-triangular form. How do you find block upper-triangular form?

Answer (score 10):

A square matrix is reducible iff the associated directed graph has smaller [strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component). So you may use a [strong component algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-based_strong_component_algorithm) to solve your problem.

Comment: Please what is an associated directed graph of a matrix?

Comment: @npisinp Let the matrix in question be $A$ and let $B=(b_{ij})$ be the matrix such that $b_{ij}=1$ if $a_{ij}\ne0$, and $b_{ij}=0$ if $a_{ij}=0$. Then $B$ is the adjacency matrix of a directed graph, and $A$ is reducible iff this directed graph has proper strongly connected components.

Answer (score 10):

There is another simple criterion for the irreducibility of a matrix with nonnegative entries. Such an $n\times n$-matrix $A$ is irreducible if and only if all entries of
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}A^i$$
are greater than $0$.

Since I do not have a reference, I will briefly sketch a proof, using the definition that *$A$ is irreducible iff for all indices $i,j$ there is an exponent $e_{i,j}$, such that entry $[A^{e_{i,j}}]_{ij}$ is positive*
(where $[C]_{ij}$ denotes the entry at $i,j$ of a matrix $C$).

Let $B$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ by replacing all non zero entries by $1$.

1. Show that $A$ is irreducible iff B is irreducible.
2. Show that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}A^i$ has only positive entries iff this is true for $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}B^i$.
3. Let $G$ be the directed graph with vertices $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, where there is an edge from $i$ to $j$ iff $b_{ij}>0$.
   Show, by induction on $m$, that the entry of $[B^m]_{ij}$ corresponds to the number of directed paths from $i$ to $j$.

According to 3., for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ the number of directed paths from $i$ to $j$ of length at most $m$ is $\left[\sum\limits_{k=0}^mB^k\right]_{ij}$.
Now the claim follows form the following equivalences:
$$\begin{array}{rl}
&\text{$B$ is an irreducible matrix.}\\
\Leftrightarrow&\text{For all $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, there is a directed path in $G$ from $i$ to $j$.}\\
\Leftrightarrow&\text{For all $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, there is a directed path in $G$ from $i$ to $j$ of length at most $n$}\\
&\text{(note that this graph has exactly $n$ vertices).}\\
\Leftrightarrow&\text{For all $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ holds $\left[\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}B^k\right]_{ij}>0$.}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Could you site the reference which gives this result ?

Comment: @kingpin: What if the matrix A has complex entries?

Answer (score 5):

A theorem may help you:

Let $A ∈ M_n$. The following are equivalent:
(a) A is irreducible.
(b) $(I + |A|)^{n-1} > 0$.
(c) $(I + M(A))^{n−1} > 0$.
(d) $\Gamma(A)$ is strongly connected.

It is Theorem 6.2.24 in *Matrix Analysis, 2nd edition*. Go check it if you need a complete proof.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A=[a_{i,j}]\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $|A|=[|a_{i,j}|]$. $A$ is irreducible IFF $|A|$ is too. Then we may assume that the $a_{i,j}$ are $\geq 0$. We have a look at the complexity of the problem: "decide whether $A$ is irreducible or not".

Of course, we do not look for a permutation of the basis vectors that triangularizes $A$ (the complexity is $O(n!)$).

We can use the test (cf. Renko Usami) $(I+A)^{n-1}>0$. Yet, the complexity is $O(n^3\log(n))$.

The best is to use the "strong component algorithm" (cf user1551). Its complexity is $O(n)$ (that is extraordinary fast, even for a $10^6\times 10^6$ matrix).

Answer (score 4):

The best place to look is this [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem). To add to the other answer, another equivalent condition is that for every index $[i,j]$, there should be a $m$ such that $(A^m)_{ij}>0$ which is naturally satisfied if the matrix entries are all positive.  If it is non-negative, then one needs to check other things.

Comment: In my opinion this answer is a bit broad, because the provided wiki link links to a theorem that uses the irreducibilty of a Matrix. That is, there is no algorithm outlined to solve the reduciblity question.