# What does the adjacency matrix for a given graph have to do with the vector space generated by the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

This question originates from my “revelation” that the identity matrix generates the world's most boring graph: all the nodes are just connected to themselves and none of them are connected to each other.

Given an adjacency matrix $A$ for a graph $G$, what do things like the determinant and eigenvalues / eigenvectors of $A$ really tell us about $G$?

If $A$ forms an orthogonal basis, then $G$ is quite “boring”, as I said. So, clearly, for “interesting” graphs, no inner product will form in the vector space defined by $A$. But $A$ still has a unique determinant, eigenvalues and eigenvectors, a inverse, a minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial, and a Jordan normal form. What do the characteristics of these properties of $A$ mean for $G$, or even $G^n$?

I understand these are likely loaded questions, but I want to find a clearer link from Graph Theory to Linear Algebra.

Comment: This is a rather broad question. You might want to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: @Math1000 I know you’re right, I just don’t have enough esoteric knowledge about both to studies to narrow it down. Any recommendations to help narrow this down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few correspondences between Graph Theory and Linear Algebra.

The most prominent would probably be the linking of graphs to their adjacency matrices, together with a slightly different definition for "the length of a path":

Let $G=(V,E,\phi)$ be a graph, and $a_1\to a_2,...,a_{n-1}\to a_n\in E$ be a path. Then we define the length of the path $a_1\to a_2\to ...\to a_{n-1}\to a_n$ as 
$$ \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \phi(a_i\to a_{i+1})$$.

Now, let $A$ be the adjancency matrix of the graph, and let $\begin{cases}A_{i,j}=1,\quad i\to j \in E\\ A_{i,j}=0,\quad i\to j\not\in E\end{cases}$ . Then the cell $(A^n)_{i,j}$ counts the number of ways to go from node $i$ to node $j$ using precisely $n$ edges.

You can then look at a normal form of $A$, e.g. diagonalization for undirected graphs, to argue that if we have an eigenvalue $\neq 0$, then we're bound to have a cycle in our graph.

A generalization of that to eigenvectors would be [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251408/applying-graph-theory-to-linear-algebra-not-the-other-way-around/3289678#3289678).

Not directly an application of the determinant of the matrix, but [Kirchhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) uses the determinants of the Laplacian matrix of the graph to calculate the number of spanning trees the graph admits.

Building on Kirchoff's Theorem, there is also the [BEST theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEST_theorem), which let's one calculate the number of eulerian circuits in a directed graph.