# Solving continuous optimization problems via reduction to combinatorial optimization problems

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

In the literature, there are examples of reductions from *discrete* optimization problems to *continuous* optimization problems.  I am aware that reductions are normally used to prove the complexity class of problems. However, I am wondering whether there are cases of continuous optimization problems solved via reduction to  a combinatorial optimization problem (or maybe the other way around). If so, could you please name a few examples?

Comment: Could you please provide examples of continuous-to-discrete reductions?

Comment: [Perhaps somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3251408/339790)